# doPost() of GAE servlet doesn't work

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I'm begginer in JSP and I have the following servlet:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HelloAppIgorServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
        RequestDispatcher disp = req.getRequestDispatcher("/mainpage.jsp");
        disp.forward(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        pw.print("Test");
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

and one JSP file called mainpage.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello there!<p>
    <form action="." method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name1" />
        <input type="submit" value="name2" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that doPost() method doesn't work. It's redirecting me to index.html page when I click the button. I'm sure that problem is not in servlets, so where can it be?

Comment: What happens if you enter the absolute URL to the servlet here: `action="."`?

Comment: Should it look like `action="ProjectName/src/org/package/HelloAppIgorServlet.java"`?

Comment: No, it should be the URL mapping component that you defined in `web.xml` for the servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate action in `<form action="." method="post">`. The action is the (relative) URL of the servlet that you defined via `<servlet-mapping>` in the `web.xml`.